# The use of VRF Lite

Tags: routing, router, vrf, vrf-lite

I have a quick question about VRF Lite.

So I understand that VRF is a technology which allows the router to build multiple virtual routing tables which divide the network on L3 with each VRF table being isolated from the other VRF tables, correct?

I can understand the use of this when it comes to MPLS, however, when exactly would we want to use VRF Lite? Lite means that it's not being used in an MPLS deployment, right? So where and why would we want to use VRF lite? Because basically, if I just want to isolate traffic or divide my network, I could just use VLANs and access lists or a firewall.

Kind regards,

David

Comment: If you want isolation on L3 use VRFs.